# Extract datetime from string with chars

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to get date from string

I have the following string

```
["07/03/22 10:29:00","1.08203","1.08205","1.08177","1.08177"
```

And I want to get just the date

```
07/03/22 10:29:00
```

I tried to use `CONVERT` function, but it doesn't works I think because the chars inside.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Date/time and string handling are two areas where many products have their own, non-standard, functions. (E.g. convert.)

Comment: The date is always in the first position?

Comment: Please read also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Is it JSON? | For what C# tag?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 and above, the following query will work by using [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator and [`ISDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression

```
DECLARE @Var AS VARCHAR (200) = '["07/03/22 10:29:00","1.08203","1.08205","1.08177","1.08177"';

SELECT Splited AS DateTime 
FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '"', ''), '[', '') AS Splited
    FROM STRING_SPLIT (@Var, ',')
) A WHERE ISDATE (Splited) = 1
```

Working [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2078b664393933938885bc3f305c2beb) query

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the format is always `["<DATETIME>","1.08203"...` then this will get you the best performance with the best performance and least amount of code.

```
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 
  '["07/03/22 10:29:00","1.08203","1.08205","1.08177","1.08177"';

SELECT (SUBSTRING(@string,3,CHARINDEX('",',@string)-3));
```

Note that splitting the string via STRING_SPLIT below will cause the optimizer to work much harder. Note the execution plans...

[image]

The STRING_SPLIT solution is cost is 792, the SUBSTRING solution cost is 12.